# What is the material and font used on the panels of most cockpits?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, aerospace-materials

I am working on a project for one of my aerospace engineering classes and was curious to see if anyone knew what type of material is used to make the panels of a cockpit (preferably a 737) as well as the font used for the lettering?

Answer (score 3):

**Materials:** You'll find several materials used for visible 737 flight-deck panels and structure. Most of the panels themselves are aluminum plates, with fiberglass, kevlar, and other plastics rounding out the space.

**Font:**  Boeing uses something close to a flavor of [Futura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)) on its panels.